# How do I approach queries like this in MySQL, Group_Concat maybe?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Database]

Ok I have the above database layout in MySQL and I'm trying to have a query that will get all information about a movie and have it formatted nicely.

Let's say I have the following information in my tables

```
movie
id        name
1         "Batman"
2         "Superman"

genre
id        name
1         "Thriller"
2         "Horror"

language  
id        lang
1         "English"
2         "Spanish"

theatre
id        name
1         "First Theatre"
2         "Second Theatre"

movie_genre
movie_id  genre_id
1         1
1         2
2         2

movie_release
id        language_id     movie_id
1         1               1
2         2               1
3         1               2

theatre_release
movie_release_id     theatre_id
1                    1
2                    2
3                    1
3                    2
```

And ideally the output would be something like this

```
movie.name   genres             releases
"Batman"     "thriller, horror" English, Theatre One
                                Spanish, Theatre Two

"Spiderman"  "Horror"           Spanish, Theatre One, Theatre Two
```

my query attempt

```
Select
     movie.name
     Group_Concat(genre.name) as genres
     Group_concat(language.lang, group_concat(theatre.name)) as releases
from
    movie
    left join movie genre on movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id
    left join genre on genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id
    left join movie_release on movie_release.movie_id = movie.id
    left join language on movie_release.language_id = language.id
    left join theatre_release on theatre_release.movie_release_id = movie_release.id
    left join theatre on theatre_release.theatre_id = theatre.id
```

Comment: As you said `GROUP_CONCAT` is the answer. Did you try anything

Comment: @Prdp yes I tried doing a group concat to concat all the languages together and a group concat inside of that to group all the theatres of that language movie release into that but you cannot have a nested group concat

Comment: Post the query we will fix it

Comment: @Prdp posted my query

Comment: SQL is NOT a way to "format nicely", it is a mistake to consider it for such a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need nested `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Use `CONCAT`  to combine the `lang` & `name` then add `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the result

```
Select
     movie.name
     Group_Concat(genre.name) as genres
     GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(language.lang,' , ',theatre.name) SEPARATOR ' | ') as releases
from ...
```

Comment: That would give me something like "(EVERY LANGUAGE) , (EVERY THEATRE)" which would make it impossible to see which language corresponds to which theatre

Comment: @user2827048 - check the update.. could give you better view